# Complete Removal of Mediatomb

Tags: 12.10, mediatomb

I recently changed to miniDLNA as my main DLNA server, however I tried removing mediatom via the normal ways (apt-get remove ...) and I still get:

```
[   33.926615] init: mediatomb main process (1340) terminated with status 1
[   33.975586] init: mediatomb main process ended, respawning
```

How do I get rid of this permanently?

J

Answer (score 2):

The service is probably still present. If so these files will be on your system:

```
/etc/mediatomb.conf
/etc/init.d/mediatomb
```

The software should be installed in:

```
/etc/mediatomb/
```

If still present remove that too.

`apt-get remove` will not remove everything; `apt-get --purge remove` removes config files too. But manually added upstart scripts you need to remove yourself.

Comment: you might want to use the init script to shut down mediatomb. In addition /etc/ usually contains config files. Using which would be a better option to find it

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to first run:

```
sudo find / -name mediatomb
```

Review the findings to make sure there are no files you want to keep  then run:

```
sudo find / -name mediatomb | xargs rm -f
```

This will force the delete of all the files found with the find command.  If you want to confirm the deletion beforehand you can run:

```
sudo find / -name mediatomb | xargs rm -i
```

Answer (score 0):

First seek it out:

```
sudo find / -name mediatomb
```

You will get a list of files and directories. Paste all your findings inline with the super dangerous recursive force delete AND include the log files like so:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mediatomb /usr/share/mediatomb /usr/bin/mediatomb /etc/logrotate.d/mediatomb /etc/mediatomb /etc/default/mediatomb /var/log/mediatomb.*
```

Then kill the running spawn:

```
$ ps axo pid,comm | grep mediatomb
[PID_NUMBER] mediatomb
$ sudo kill -9 [PID_NUMBER]
```

Not wise to use wild cards lazy whiz's. Enjoi & Whistle

Answer (score 0):

Your `sudo find / -name mediatomb` finds files AND directories. `rm` will only delete files, you must use `rmdir` to remove (empty) directories.`sudo find / -name mediatomb -type f` will find only files. Rather than traverse the whole filesystem, I suggest using `rm -rf` instead (read `man rm`).

While `sudo` runs the `find` as `root`, the `xargs` command is run as the user, which causes several of your errors.

Since `mediatomb` is an installed package, you should use a package manager to remove it - that will find ALL the pieces, and update its database. `sudo apt-get purge mediatomb` will do the trick the right way.